# Select collection if its array contains id in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my code:

```
const events = await Event.find({'isFinished': false})
    .where('attendants.employers').in(user._id);
```

Here's the model:

```
var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    'attendants': {
        'seekers': [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        'employers': [],
    },
    'isFinished': {'type': Boolean, 'default': false},
});
```

I want to grab the events, which have the user's id in their `attendants.employers` array. I know I can filter them after downloading all events, but this is really inefficient.

Current code doesn't return any value. I tried flipping it around like so `.where(user._id).in('attendants.employers');`. But this causes node to say:

> Error: in() must be used after where() when called with these arguments

Any idea how to achieve it, without downloading the data, and filtering it on the server?

Comment: You can use simple find query with the `.dot` notation, `Event.find({ 'attendants.employers': user._id })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `find` should look something like this:

```
Event.find({'isFinished': false, 'attendants.employers': user._id})
```

You do not need to do the `where` etc since in your find you list the `rules` and they will be `AND-ed` together.

You can use `$in` the other way around where you want to find out if a field in your document is `IN` a range of values.